# how to move between segments on simple button click in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I have taken `ion-segment` in which i have created 3 segments. Inside each segment I have created a button and I want to switch from one segment to other by simply clicking on that button click instead of clicking the *segmentButton*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like follows:

```
    <ion-content>
  <!-- Segment in content -->
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="relationship" color="primary">
    <div value="friends">
      <button click="changeTab('enemies')" value"=btn1"/>
    </div>
    <div value="enemies">
      <button click="changeTab('friends')" value"=btn2"/>
    </div>
  </ion-segment>
</ion-content>
```

Then in you .ts file you can define changeTab as:

```
changeTab(value){
     this.relationship=value:
}
```

Comment: Great...It it's working then please accept the answer .